# Pandas Dataframe select multiple discontinuous columns/slices

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I have dataframe with >100 columns. I am trying to select the columns 0~32 and #83. It seems that 1 slice works fine with the code below.

```
df_new = df[df.columns[0:32]]
```

It does not work with 2 slices code below though. How do I fix the problem?

```
df_new = df[df.columns[0:32, 83]]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `np.r_` indexer in conjunction with `iloc`, like this:

```
df.iloc[:, np.r_[0:32, 83]]
```

---

```
np.r_[0:32, 83]

array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 83])
```

Comment: Unfortunately first/last like this doesn't work, `df.iloc[:, np.r_[0, -3:]]`. If anyone has a solution to that using `np.r_` it would be a nice addition to this answer.

Comment: @DavidParks I'm surprised this isn't better supported but here you go: `c = df.shape[1]; df.iloc[:, np.r_[0, nc-3:nc]]`

Comment: @cs95 I think it will be good to add the comment in the answer.

Comment: After using this method (`np.r_`), when I extract a column of a dataframe it becomes a DataFrame (type is: `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`) instead of a series. Why does this happen? Any way to make this a series?

Answer (score 3):

`np.r_` is an excellent answer. The other approach would be to construct it with list and range.

Consider this example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([range(10)],range(10))
cols = list(range(0,5))+[8]              # 0,1,2,3,4,8
df.iloc[:,cols]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also interest in this problem. We can choose several separate lines or columns. But it seems slicing operation could be done only once on each axis. Like the following one.

```
new_df=df.iloc[[2,3,4],[3:4]]
```

Maybe we can slice first and then concatenate them together.

```
df1=df.iloc[[2:4],:]
df2=df.iloc[[8:10],:]
new_df=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=0)
```

Comment: This is slicing rows, but op wants columns

Comment: I definitely considered selecting 2 slices and concatenating, but thought there must be an easier way which was shown in the first answer.