# Removing single and range of columns in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

What is the fastest way to drop `columns[3]` and `columns[9:15]`? 
(I'm only able to remove the columns in 2 steps using the `df.drop` method)

```
    1  2  3  4  5  6 ..  n
A   x  x  x  x  x  x ..  x
B   x  x  x  x  x  x ..  x
C   x  x  x  x  x  x ..  x
```

Comment: Related : [Pandas Dataframe select multiple discontinuous columns/slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143469/pandas-dataframe-select-multiple-discontinuous-columns-slices)

Answer (score 4):

You can, in fact, use [`pd.DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) in one step. You can use [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to combine multiple indices and ranges. Here's a demo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((3, 20)))

print(df.columns)  # RangeIndex(start=0, stop=20, step=1)

res = df.drop(np.r_[3, 9:15], 1)

print(res.columns)

# Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using simple `loc` and `isin`

```
cols = df.columns.tolist()
to_remove = cols[9:15] + [cols[3]]

df.loc[:, ~df.columns.isin(to_remove)]
```

but `np.r_` is so nice I'd go with it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use as below:

```
>>> df
   A  B   C   D
0  0  1   2   3
1  4  5   6   7
2  8  9  10  11

>>> df.drop(['B', 'C'], axis=1)
   A   D
0  0   3
1  4   7
2  8  11
```