# How to drop multiple columns (using column names) from a dataframe using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame `df` with around 200 columns. I want to drop the columns with an index position from 50 to 90 and 120 to 170 with its name rather than its index position. How to do that.

I cannot use:

```
df.drop('column name', axis=1)
```

directly because there are so many columns to drop and I cannot really type each of its column names as in the above cases.

**I am interested in knowing how to select the columns from particular column name `column50` to another column name `column90` and `column120` to `column170` rather than with the `int`**

Comment: Also: [Removing single and range of columns in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52245582/7851470)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df.drop(df.columns.to_series()["column_name_1":"column_name_2"], axis=1)
```

By converting to a series you can actually use a range to drop. You'd just need to know the column names.

Comment: Is it possible to select the columns from ````column_name_4 to column_name_6```` along with ````column_name_1: column_name_2````

Comment: Possibly, but I'm not sure about the syntax.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`np.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to do this:

```
import numpy
idx = np.r_[50:90, 120:170]

df.drop(df.columns[idx], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

From the `np.r_` docs:

> Translates slice objects to concatenation along the first axis.

In your case, it concatenates non-contiguous slices of arrays which you can use in df.drop command.

Answer (score 4):

For non-contiguous [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/slice.html) objectss, always prefer to use [`np.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html).

The main goal for `np.r_` is:

> Translates slice objects to concatenation along the first axis.

Given that you have now concatenated, non-contiguous slice blocks, it gets easy to perform operations. You can use `drop`, `loc`, `iloc` or whatever logic you want (not much gain here beyond readability).

For example,

```
df = df.iloc[:, np.r_[50:90, 120:170]]
```

or, as suggested by @anky

```
df[df.columns ^ df.columns[np.r_[50:90,120:170]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a list of columns like this:

```
idx = list(range(50,90)) + list(range(120,170))

df = df.drop(df.columns[idx], axis=1)
```